# passing parameter in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i tray to make number generator by using ionic first view contain input type number

```
<ion-view view-title="Home View"> 
<ion-content class="padding">
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label">number</span>
 <input type="number" ng-model="num">
</label>

      <button ui-sref="page2" class="button button-block button-positive" >
      View List
    </button>
    </ion-content>
     </ion-view>
```

and the second page to list the number from 0 to number enters by the user

```
<ion-view view-title="list view">
<ion-content class="padding">

<h1>{{number}}</h1>

<button ui-sref="page1" class="button button-block button-positive" >
      GO TO HOME
 </button>
 </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

and this is the controllers.js

```
.controller('page1', function($scope, $rootScope) {

 $rootScope.num="";

  })

  .controller('page2', function($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

   var number= $stateParams.page2;

    $scope.n=number;



    });
```

how can i pass the number in page 1 to page 2 and make list from 0 th that number

Answer (score 0):

I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38917051/6691908) a question like yours about passing parameters through pages.

Check it!